# Assigning a value from pointer indexing

Tags: c, gcc

I am writing a program that needs optimization. I have a pointer of n integers and need to save them in different arrays but sharing the memory. My question is:

Is this

```
int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
int** ptr2 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = i;
    ptr2[i] = &ptr[i];
}
```

equivalent to this?

```
int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
int* ptr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = i;
    ptr2[i] = ptr[i];
}
```

I mean, in the second case the value of `*(ptr[i])` is copied into `*(ptr2[i])` or `ptr[i]` and `ptr2[i]` point to the same memory address?

-- EDIT --

The reason I ask is I have a png image saved in an `uint8_t* data` with R, G and B pixels contiguous, so for example, for the first pixel `(R, G, B) = (data[0], data[1], data[2])`, for the second pixel, `(R, G, B) = (data[3], data[4], data[5])` and so on. So I need to separate the three channels by storing the values in three different arrays, for obvious reasons I want to share the memory of the values used in the `data` array and the ones used in the `r_channel`, `g_channel` and `b_channel`. So I don't know if I should declare each channel as `uint8_t*` or `uint8_t**` and assign its pixels like shown in the code snippets I posted as examples.

Comment: No they are not equivalent. `int *` is not the same as `int **` as one is a pointer to an `int` and the other is a pointer to a pointer of an `int`. No need to cast the return value of `malloc()` these days with modern C compilers.

Comment: Rather than asking a question about a specific approach to some unspecified optimization problem, why don't you instead ask a question about the optimization problem itself. What do you mean by saving in different arrays but sharing the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code `ptr` is an array of integers(dynamically created) and is storing the values from 0 to 10, `ptr2` is a integer pointer array where each element (`int *`) points to an element (`int`) of ptr.

> ```
> int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
> int** ptr2 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*10);
> for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
>     ptr[i] = i;
>     ptr2[i] = &ptr[i];
> }
> ```

The following code creates a copy of ptr in ptr2.

> ```
> int* ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
> int** ptr2 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*10);
> for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
>     ptr[i] = i;
>     ptr2[i] = &ptr[i];
> }
> ```

So in example 2 if the value of an element in ptr changes it won't get reflected in `ptr` whereas in example 1 if value in `ptr` changes it would automatically get reflected in `prt2` since elements in `ptr2` are pointing directly to `ptr` elements.

If you just want to access the data you can do that using pointer arithmetics e.g.
for nth pixel `R = data[3*n+0]; G = data[3*n+1]; B = data[3*n+2];`

But if you intend to store it in memory creating a copy seems more logical as it would require less space, since `sizeof(uint8_t) <= sizeof(uint8_t *)`

Comment: Thanks, I thought pointers required less space than copying the data of `uint8_t`. But finally I guess I will have to use just pointer arithmetics and don't separate the channels at all to minimize the memory usage.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)